# Predicting the convergence state/class of a noisy time series, as early as possible

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, prediction, convergence

I have data from a process that converges over time, although the time to converge is variable and the convergence process is quite non-linear.  Moreover, the convergence can be to saturation either approaching 100% or 0%.  I've drawn an idealised sketch to exemplify:

[image]

It is fairly clear to the eye which of high/low end states the system will converge to some time before it does converge. But I don't know how to quantify this, or try to build a predictive model to say what the outcome will be early on in the process.  For each experimental repeat, I have the time series data (normalized) and can manually classify as a high or low run (or use a threshold to decide based on the last 10%, say).  So I can apply labels for a supervised learning method.

What statistical methods might be appropriate in this case? I'm not too familiar with ML, but many introductory texts that I have read on time series prediction seem to ask for a *stationary process* -- and clearly this is not the case -- so presumably these are all ruled out? Conversely, ignoring the fact that the data to learn from are from a time series would presumably cause problems because of the high level of auto-correlation?

Any suggestions v welcome!